# Decrypt Filevault on a (removed) startup disk

Tags: macos, external-disk, encryption, filevault

I had a hardware issue with my old Macbook Pro which required me to remove the boot drive. I have attached it via USB to a new Macbook and can unlock and mount it, etc. However I don't see anyway of permanently decrypting the drive. Is this possible? I can see the drive in Finder, but it doesn't have any context options to decrypt.

I need to do this as the disk is in a strange state where the OS is half re-installed (it won't complete, keeps giving weird errors about "Installer resources not found" etc) - However as I haven't erased, removed any partitions or deleted anything explicitly I'm hoping that file recovery software will get my data back, but this relies on it being unencrypted. Any other solutions would also be welcomed!

Comment: Which MBP model did you remove the disk from? Also, which state is the disk in? Can you temporarily decrypt it to access the files?

Comment: There is some explanatory gap & some technical misunderstanding in your question: is the hardware issue related to the (failed) OS reinstall? Is the unlocked volume empty? If you unlock and mount the drive you can already use file recovery software (i.e no permanent decryption necessary).

Comment: Its a 2012 model with a 500GB magnetic disk. I'm not sure of the exact spec because in an unrelated incident the Li-Po battery exploded so the whole thing has been disposed of. When I first connect the disk it asks for the Filevault password which I enter and it unlocks the drive. What I then have is a volume called "Base System" which I presume is a recovery volume. When viewed in disk utility it shows approx 490GB of free space, which is confusing as the disk was practically full and all I did was to start an in place OS reinstall, which many articles claim is non-destructive to user data.

Comment: I'm sort of hoping that the OS reinstall process has temporarily hidden the data volume, which would be reverted once the process completes, although that is a very long shot.